# Сортировка массива по значению ключа с использованием регулярного выражения

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Здравствуйте. Помогите с сортировкой массива.

```
 [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [VALUE] => г. Москва
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [VALUE] => д. Волки
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [VALUE] => х. Орехово
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [VALUE] => пос. Братылово
        )
```

Необходимо отсортировать по значению ключа [VALUE], в алфавитном порядке, при этом игнорировать префиксы (г., д. ...). 
Результат должен быть:

1. пос. Братылово
2. д. Волки
3. г. Москва
4. х. Орехово

   ```
   function cmp($a, $b)
   {
   };    
   usort($Array, 'cmp');
   ```

Спасибо!

Comment: А нельзя ли постить массивы в виде кода(var_export, например)? Чтобы это можно было использовать в ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- В функции компаратора порезать значения по пробелу
  *3 параметр limit позволяет порезать по первому пробелу на 2 части*
- Сравнить выделенные строки удобным способом, *(вернуть {-1, 0, 1})*

*синтаксис php >=7*

```
$data = [
    ['id' => 1, 'VALUE' => 'г. Москва'],
    ['id' => 2, 'VALUE' => 'д. Волки'],
    ['id' => 3, 'VALUE' => 'х. Орехово'],
    ['id' => 4, 'VALUE' => 'пос. Братылёво'],
];

usort($data, function($a, $b) {
   $a = preg_split('/\s+/', $a['VALUE'], 2);
   $b = preg_split('/\s+/', $b['VALUE'], 2);
   return $a[1] <=> $b[1];
});

echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)."\n";
echo json_encode(array_map(function($a){return $a['VALUE'];}, $data), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)."\n";
[{"id":4,"VALUE":"пос. Братылёво"},{"id":2,"VALUE":"д. Волки"},{"id":1,"VALUE":"г. Москва"},{"id":3,"VALUE":"х. Орехово"}]
["пос. Братылёво","д. Волки","г. Москва","х. Орехово"]
```

[3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/tQDpL)

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!